# Append inside Array inside Object - Watson Assistant

Tags: javascript, watson-assistant

I've created this Array:

```
{"intent":[],"canonica":[],"entities":[{"name":[],"value":[]}]}
```

Now I have to append an value inside `entities.value` but append can't work in this case.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the snippet it seems you have created an object not an array. If so then do

`data.entities[0].value.push(1);` where `data.entities` will first get the `entities` array from the data object

```js
let data = {
  "intent": [],
  "canonica": [],
  "entities": [{
    "name": [],
    "value": []
  }]
}


data.entities[0].value.push(1);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

do this `entitles[0].value.push()`